# How to put phone number dynamically on href?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

How can i put the phone number dynamically on href tel:

```
                <q-item tag="a" href="tel:9774041049" clickable v-ripple>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

```
<q-item tag="a" :href="'tel:' + number " clickable v-ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a country code in that phone number but you got the right syntax

### Example

`<a href="tel:+45157054509">61709</a>`

Comment: yes..this is just an example for it